# People Search Result based on column value within a list

Tags: search-results, people-search

I have a list called `New Starters` which is populated with the name of everyone that has started within the previous 2 weeks. The name is entered into a `Person or Group` column type. There is also a `Yes / No` column called `Display`.

I want to be able to set up a Search results web part that returns the people in the name column where the `Display column = Yes`.

I have looked all over and cannot see anyway that shows how to do this. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If I were designing this solution I would not store it in a list. I would either use the existing anniversary date field on the user profile or create a Boolean field on the User Profile for this purpose. Then you can just query the user profiles with search to get the users.

If you want to stick with your current implementation you could create a query for your specific list (based on `path`) or a better approach is to create a new content type and use a query like `ContentType=AnniversaryPerson`. You will have to have to create Managed Properties for the fields you want to display or query like DisplayColumn.

.

Comment: I was trying to get it to do it via date, that way no user input would be required. But struggled to do this and thought a list might be a better quicker option

Comment: It all depends on the goal of the solution, the management overhead, the final look and feel. All theses factors would drive the choice of the "right" solution. There is no, one, "right", answer. The beauty (and bother) of SharePoint is the flexibility and possibility that you can solve a problem several different ways.

Comment: I am trying to get the lowest management overheads possible. I thought that the anniversary date approach would be the best but as I could not get this to work I have tried the list approach (which does have some benefits). I have queried based on path but the results only show disp.aspx forms, not the people search results. I tried to create a new people based result source based on path for this list but this returned nothing

Comment: You won't get a People result by default since the content type is a list item. You will need to create your own display template and display your fields as needed. This is where a custom Content Type can help. It makes the query easier. Then your custom display template can show the result any way you like.

Comment: Thank you. I am on paternity leave now but will try this when I get back!